# the file directory on other computer C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am working with c# in window application, and I am hardcoding the file path into the program. But if I move the application to another PC, that absolutely can't find out the directory of the file.

like this:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ReadCsv("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\print_report_system\\price.csv");
```

Is it someway to solve this problem?

Sorry for my poor english.

Thx a lot.

Comment: your question itself has the answer... how will it find a file which has been hardcoded with respect to your system?

Comment: I will stop hard-coding...  And I am going to redesign my program.  Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, put the filepath into the config file app.config

```
<appSettings>
<add name="filePath" value="PATH HERE"/>
</appSettings>
```

and use it like this

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ReadCsv(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"]);
```

And the change that config file whenever you move the app to the correct file path in the new PC

Comment: I would also suggest that they do a check to see if the File Path exist and no matter what at least in code once it reads from the config file, the code can check if(!Directoy.Exist){ } then create it.. better to check than assume, in case the OP forgets to create the Directory.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have fixed the problem.